# How to overlay an earth-like grid on the text in GIMP?

Tags: gimp, text, grids, overlay

How do I create a text with a grid overlay as shown in this image?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new layer above your text layer.
2. Place your grid element on this new layer.
3. Create a clipping mask with the layer that has your grid element.(In Photoshop, you right click on the layer and select "Create Clipping Mask")
4. Re-position your grid element so it is on top of your text!

You can find more information on this technique by searching for how to create a clipping mask or masks in your graphic application of choice.

Comment: And in GIMP, step 3 is to create a layer mask - from the text layer's alpa channel, for example.